# JavaScript equivalent of this simple php

Tags: php, javascript, phpjs

please can somebody let me know how to do the following PHP in JavaScript. The vaibles in PHP are Parameters in Javascript. If all three Parameters are set then I would like a PHP script to execute:

```
<?php     
if isset($nation,$service,$slider)
    {
//execute php script
    }       
?>
```

Thanks for looking, and maybe helping!

To clear any confusion, I require all the PHP above to be converted into it JavaScript equivalent.

On top of this I would like a way of executing a PHP script within the JavaScript if all 3 Parameters are set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming none of your variables have a zero or null value, for example, if they're all strings, the shortest way to write variable checks is to just use them:

```
function blah (nation, service, slider)
{
    if (nation && service && slider)
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

If any of those vars have the value 0, false or null when set then this would not be the correct method.  If you want the equivalent of the `isset` function, you could use this:

```
function isset()
{
    for (var i=0, l=arguments.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (typeof arguments[i] == "undefined" || typeof arguments[i] == "null")
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Use it the same as you would the php function, e.g. `isset(nation,service,slider);`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the great [**phpjs.org**](http://phpjs.org) stuff. It's a **port of PHP functions into JavaScript**.

**[The isset() function](http://phpjs.org/functions/isset:454):**

```
function isset () {
    // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: FremyCompany
    // +   improved by: Onno Marsman
    // *     example 1: isset( undefined, true);
    // *     returns 1: false
    // *     example 2: isset( 'Kevin van Zonneveld' );
    // *     returns 2: true

    var a=arguments, l=a.length, i=0;

    if (l===0) {
        throw new Error('Empty isset'); 
    }

    while (i!==l) {
        if (typeof(a[i])=='undefined' || a[i]===null) { 
            return false; 
        } else { 
            i++; 
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
allVarsAvailable = isset(nation,service,slider);
```

Comment: Yup can recommend this aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to do an [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) call. If you were to use a framework like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), the code would be something like:

```
if ((typeof nation != 'undefined') && (typeof service != 'undefined') && (typeof slider != 'undefined')) {
    $.get("<your script>", function(data){
         alert("Data Received: " + data);
    });
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but looks right:

```
function isset(variable_name){
  return(typeof(window[variable_name])!='undefined');
}
```

Note that `variable_name` is not a variable itself, but it's name.

Comment: You should have tested.  For this to work, type of `variable_name` would need to be a string, which isn't the equivalent to php's function.  Remove the `window[]` and just have `variable_name`.